# What does the c++ class access keyword "signals" mean?

Tags: c++, qt, class, keyword

I came across a declaration similar to this (names changed per [NDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement)):

```
class Foo
{
    int  bar;

 public:
    explicit Foo (Fu *parent = NULL);

 private:
    void somefunc (String);

 signals:        // ??? what does this do ???
    void windowClosed();
};
```

This is compiled successfully by g++ 4.4.7 (from about 2012).  Additionally, vim recognizes it as a keyword similar to `public` and `private` by highlighting them in brown.  (Dis)similiarly, vim uses green to highlight the keywords `namespace`, `class`, `void`, `int`, `double`, `float`, `char`, `unsigned`, etc.

The Stackoverflow code formatter does *not* highlight `signals` above like it does `public` and `private`!

It has proved quite difficult to Google for this (lots of noise), but I haven't found anything mentioning it, not even on SO.  I also looked in the [enhancements section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html) of the g++ documentation.

This codebase is large (23+ million lines), oldish (~1998), and has a distinct accent.  For example, the same class definition has the class access `private slots:` before two member functions.  So it is possible there is some `#define` obfuscation or trickery going on, but I can't find it using `grep`.  It is possible g++ has been altered, but its `--version` output does not indicate modification.

Comment: It isn't a keyword http://ideone.com/54UsaM

Comment: Have a look at this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't a keyword, if you're using a framework such as Qt it adds up 'keywords' to the language to provide additional functionality that isn't part of the standard.

In Qt for example this code gets preproccessed by the MOC(Meta-Object Compiler), `signals` is defined in `qobjectdefs.h` as `#define signals public`, the moc checks for this macro to add meta-code and provide the actual signal-slot functionality, the generated code is put into a file with a name such as 'moc_myClass.cpp'.

Comment: Actually this isn't quite accurate either. `moc` doesn't change the code itself before it gets compiled (how would this work for headers that get compiled in many translation units?), it just does *additional* processing to generate the metadata code. The code compiles as-is in a normal C++ compiler, by virtue of the Qt "keywords" being defined to something else via macros.

Comment: @Cameron I don't think I said it changed the code itself? I'll change my wording by "turns this signals into actually valid C++ code" I mean "it will add up the code that provides the signal-slot functionality"

Comment: You said it changes the code (into valid code) "and that's what gets compiled" :-)

Comment: @Cameron well it generates valid code, as Qt macros and 'keywords' aren't valid C++, how would you word it?

Comment: Aha!  In the long list of header files, there are four peculiar includes like `#include <QMainWindow>` and `#include <QProcess>`.  So apparently it is not pure c++.  The Makefile does not immediately succumb to scrutiny, but this at least explains what is going on.

Comment: I would say that the code is already valid C++ (by dint of these special "keywords" being `#define`d to something harmless), but that `moc` treats them specially in a separate pass in order to auto-generate metadata code.

Comment: @Cameron sure the could would be valid if we `#define` those "keywords" to something harmless, if we don't then it is not.

Answer (score 3):

These are not c++ keywords! c++ will not compile them, unless you include a header from the Qt library which will remove them with the preprocessor using:

```
//from qobjectdefs.h
#     define slots
#     define signals public
```

These are "tags" used by the Qt Library Preprocessor (moc, Meta Object Compiler) for processing them.

They mark methods which are used in a signal-slot communication mechanism between objects. moc will process them only if the class is marked with the Q_OBJECT macro, and these classes must inherit from QObject.

From these, moc create a companion class in moc_xxxxx.h and moc_xxxxx.cpp source files, with the necessary code for handling the signal/slot mechanism.

Even if you have Qt headers and libraries, you will generally not be able to link the code without the qmake generated sources.

Comment: How does c++ incorporate Qt library code?  AFAIK, this is is pure c++.

Comment: "c++ compilers will just ignore these keywords" not *ignore*, but they will fail to compile the code. Aside from this, your answer is fine.

Comment: The Qt preprocessor is `moc`, not `qmake`. And the compiler does not just "ignore" these keywords -- they are macros defined to `public` or `private` (I can't remember which) in one of the included Qt headers.

Comment: @wallyk this won't compile as pure C++

Comment: @KeillRandor : but it does compile (not link) without moc. I do not know how, but it compiles

Comment: This would be a great answer if it didn't claim _"c++ compilers will just ignore these keywords."_. They're not keywords (they're just preprocessor tokens) and C++ compilers will give an error if they see them, they need to be removed/replaced by the preprocessor before the compiler ever sees them.

Comment: @galinette: If it compiles without moc, it simply means that one of your included header files defined `signals` to be a macro that means something completely innocent from C++ point of view, i.e. `public`, `private` or `protected`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely : no, the preprocessor does not alter the source. It just creates companion classes. The original source containing these keywords is sent to the c++ compiler unmodified. The keywords are likely removed by a macro

Comment: @galinette NOPE, it does not compile without including Qt headers. see the ideone example provided by Alejandro.

Answer (score 1):

`signals` is a macro defined by the Qt framework that is translated to `public` during compilation while serving as a *beacon* to Qt's `moc` preprocessor for implementing observer-like class relations with "signals" and "slots". Other similar Qt macros include `slots` and `Q_SLOTS`.